# jQuery - decrease heading size

Tags: jquery

I would like to decrease all headings on my page by one

Examples:

`<h1>Hi</h1> -> <h2>Hi</h2>
<h3>Moin</h3> -> <h4>Hi</h4>`

What's the best way to achieve that in jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Any attempts from your side ?

Comment: Can you add more info what you need? If you want to increase or decrease font size. Try here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241457/increasing-decreasing-font-size-on-button-click

Comment: Actually I wanted to do something like that for a custom class, but realized that with attributes it's much easier: let headIndex = parseInt($(this).attr("data-head-index")) || 0;
Still I think the original question might be interesting in general.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be best solution, but you can try this:

```
$("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5").each(function() {

  if($(this).is("h1")) {
    $(this).replaceWith("<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>");
  }
  else if($(this).is("h2")){
    $(this).replaceWith("<h3>" + $(this).text() + "</h3>");
  }
  else if($(this).is("h3")){
    $(this).replaceWith("<h4>" + $(this).text() + "</h4>");
  }
  else if($(this).is("h4")){
    $(this).replaceWith("<h5>" + $(this).text() + "</h5>");
  }
  else if($(this).is("h5")){
    $(this).replaceWith("<h6>" + $(this).text() + "</h6>");
  }

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gocegisedo/edit?html,js,output)**